# Pointer arithmetic with variables not in an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following question; If a is an int array with 10 Element I can define pointers

```
int*b=&a[3]; 
int*c=&[2];
```

I can then do arithmetic operations with these pointers like `int d=a-c;` which will return the number of int values in the array between b and c. So my question is if I am also allowed to do such pointer arithmetic operations for any variables which may not be in an array. For example:

```
int a=10; 
int b=20; 
int*c=&a; 
int* d=&b;
```

and then do `int e=d-c;` or `int*e=c+1;`

The reason I ask is that I have received conflicting information about whether this leads to undefined behaviour,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, here's the conflict breaker. You may not. Doing so would be UB.

Comment: `intb=&a[3]` and `intc=&a[2]` are not not syntatically correct.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would a comparison if(p1<p2) work for such pointers?

Comment: _Would a comparison if(p1<p2) work for such pointers?_ it would work on most implementations but it also would be UB.

Comment: One *reason* for the rule is that in a segmented memory architecture two unrelated variables might reside in different segments. And you might not get any useful information from subtracting two `segment:offset` pairs. The elements of an array, on the other hand, are presumably in the same segment (otherwise things like array indexing will be difficult).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[expr.add] standard draft:

> 4. When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
>      of the pointer operand. If the expression P points to element x[i] of an array object x with n elements,<sup>86</sup>
>      the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element
>      x[i + j] if 0 ≤ i + j ≤ n; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. Likewise, the expression P - J points to the
>      (possibly-hypothetical) element x[i − j] if 0 ≤ i − j ≤ n; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> 5. When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the type of the result is an
>      implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_-
>      t in the  header (21.2). If the expressions P and Q point to, respectively, elements x[i] and x[j]
>      of the same array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i − j; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>      [ Note: If the value i − j is not in the range of representable values of type std::ptrdiff_t, the behavior is
>      undefined. — end note ]
>
> ---
>
> 86) An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose; see 8.3.1. A
>   pointer past the last element of an array x of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer to a hypothetical element
>   x[n] for this purpose; see 6.9.2.

---

`c+1` is well defined, because it would be pointing one past the "single-element array" that the variable is treated as for the purpose of the quoted rule, and therefore satisfies `0 ≤ 0 + 1 ≤ 1`. But it would not be well defined to indirect that pointer, since it past the end of that "array".

`d-c` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: *because it would be pointing one past the "single-element array"* I don't think you can treat any variable as a single-element array. It is tempting but there doesn't seem to be any permit to do so in the standard.

Comment: @n.m. the standard rules can treat a variable as a single-element array and at least this one does. The programmer cannot (except to the extent that the standard allows).